# "Error: could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher." While running a native-image build using GraalVM

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have created a Sprint Boot Application and exported it as a Jar file using 'mvn package'. This Jar is a standalone executable file which do not need any other dependent files to run. The only dependent files the main class need are already packaged within the jar and I am using InputStream to load the dependent files during runtime. So basically the Jar file is looking for the dependent files within itself and this is all working fine.

I want to convert this executable jar into a native imagine (exe file in my case) and so I ran the command

> *native-image -cp "myJarFile.jar" com.example.MyApp*

And the exe gets build successfully. But when I run it, it's giving me the below error in the command prompt

> Error: could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarLauncher caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

`Note: But, when I place the orginal jar file in the same directory of the exe file and run the exe, the spring app gets deployed.`

Just to be sure that something is not getting mishandled, I have put the jar file in a seperate location on my machine and ran it using the command:

> *java -cp "myJarFile.jar" com.example.MyApp*

And the spring app deploys on port 8080 successfully.

I have analysed the jar contents and could see the folders **BOOT-INF/** , **META-INF/** and all the other necessary lib folders.

What could be going wrong and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an unusual way to build a native image for a Spring Boot app. Have you considered using the Maven or Gradle build plugins to do it instead?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I looked into the graalvm maven plugin. But that builds as a docker image. I don't want to use docker to build the native imagine. But this method I tried should also work right. The exe is functional when I place the jar file in the same folder. It's a problem with how the image is build. I have no clue what options I am missing.

Comment: With build plugins, Docker is optional, you can build without it too. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.native-build-tools). What you are missing is likely reflection/proxy/provider etc config files which can take quite some time to do properly. Plugins just (try to) do this work automatically for you.